# How can you use pigpio's set_servo_pulsewidth with an i2c address?

Tags: python, i2c, pigpio

I've tried to use hexadecimal for the GPIO address to see if it would work with GPA0 on the MCP23017

```
import pigpio
import time
pi = pigpio.pi()
gpio_num = 0x21
while True:
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(gpio_num, 1500)
```

but this results in the error

```
  File "i2cpigpio.py", line 6, in <module>
    pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(gpio_num, 1500)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1647, in set_servo_pulsewidth
    self.sl, _PI_CMD_SERVO, user_gpio, int(pulsewidth)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 979, in _u2i
    raise error(error_text(v))
pigpio.error: 'no permission to update GPIO'
```

I also tried using one of Adafruit's libraries (with python3) to see if that would make it more compatible

```
import pigpio
import time
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017
import board
import busio
import digitalio
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23017(i2c)  # MCP23017
pin0 = mcp.get_pin(0)
pin0.switch_to_output(value=True)

pi = pigpio.pi()
gpio_num = pin0
while True:
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(gpio_num, 1500)
```

but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "i2cpigpio.py", line 15, in <module>
    pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(gpio_num, 1500)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 1647, in set_servo_pulsewidth
    self.sl, _PI_CMD_SERVO, user_gpio, int(pulsewidth)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pigpio.py", line 993, in _pigpio_command
    sl.s.send(struct.pack('IIII', cmd, p1, p2, 0))
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

since pin0 doesn't represent a Broadcom SOC channel. What can I use for the GPIO number to send a pulsewidth to GPA0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pigpio only provides PWM and servo pulses to the Pi GPIO on the expansion header.  For the Pis with the 40 pin header this means (Broadcom) GPIO 0-27 inclusive.

In practical terms I doubt you will have much joy using a MCP23017 to provide servo signals.  It will be extremely difficult to time synchronise accurately on/off pulses over the relatively slow I2C bus.

Comment: I see, is there any other method you might recommend for when you need more servos than the expansion header will allow (preferably without servo jitter)?

Comment: Look at pca9685 based modules.

Comment: Put pca9685 into eBay search